# Two footnotes in a heading, only one is displayed at the end of the page

Tags: sectioning, footnotes, titlesec

I'm adding two footnotes to a section heading:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[stable]{footmisc}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\begin{document}
\section{test
\footnote{This is footnote no1.}
\footnote{This is footnote no2.}
}
\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

The heading will have both of the footnotes, but at the end of the page only the second is displayed.
The problem appears to be `\usepackage{titlesec}`, because it works fine without it.

[image]

Stuff I specified in `\usepackage{titlesec}`:

```
\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}} 
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\arabic{subsection}} 
\renewcommand\thesubsubsection{\arabic{subsubsection}} 
\titleformat{\section}[block]{\Large\scshape\centering}{\thesection}{1em}{} 
\titleformat{\subsection}[block]{\large\scshape}{\thesection.\thesubsection}{1em}{} 
\titleformat{\subsubsection}[block]{\large\scshape}{\thesection.\thesubsection.\thesubsubsection}{1em}{}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `titlesec` package redefines `\footnote` when processing a sectional title in such a way as to store the footnote text in a save bin (called `\ttl@fn`). A second footnote overwrites the contents of this storage bin, so in the end you only get the last footnote.

A workaround is to use the `\footnotemark` and `\footnotetext` mechanism just for the cases (rare, I hope) when you need two footnotes. My advice is of never using footnotes in titles.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[stable]{footmisc}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}} 
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\arabic{subsection}} 
\renewcommand\thesubsubsection{\arabic{subsubsection}} 

\titleformat{\section}[block]
  {\Large\scshape\centering}
  {\thesection}
  {1em}
  {} 
\titleformat{\subsection}[block]
  {\large\scshape}
  {\thesection.\thesubsection}
  {1em}
  {} 
\titleformat{\subsubsection}[block]
  {\large\scshape}
  {\thesection.\thesubsection.\thesubsubsection}
  {1em}
  {}

\begin{document}

\section[test]{test\footnotemark\ \footnotemark}
\addtocounter{footnote}{-1}\footnotetext{This is footnote no1.}
\addtocounter{footnote}{1}\footnotetext{This is footnote no2.}

\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

Don't forget the optional argument without the footnotes, or they will also appear in the table of contents and in the headings.

[image]

<sub>**Note** The image has been produced by reducing the text height</sub>